# The best way to reduce a set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I was always told that the best way to guess what number someone's thinking of is to split the set into half continuously until I reach one item (ex. guess number from 1-100; 1-50; 1-25; 1-12; 1-6; 1-3 ; 1) and that it will generally be guessed in $ \lceil \log_2 n \rceil $ where $n$ is the set size.

However, [this video](https://youtu.be/tE2dZLDJSjA) seems to come to a better conclusion on splitting a set. They propose a 3 move solution in a set of 12, where $ \lceil \log_2 12 \rceil = 4$.

How are these different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re getting very different information in the two puzzles. In the guessing game at each stage you simply learn which of two complementary sets contains the number. Since there are only $2^n$ possible sequences of *yes* and *no*, $n$ stages can distinguish at most $2^n$ different numbers.

In the coin problem at each stage you learn whether certain coins are potentially light, potentially heavy, or definitely genuine. This is demonstrably more information, since the $12$-coin problem can be solved in $3$ weighings even though $2^3<12$.

Comment: I understand that there has to be more data in the coin example, but I'm struggling got understand where. The coin example can also be modeled as a yes/no problem (is one side heavier) and yet we have more data coming out of it somewhere

Comment: @user760900: But it cannot be modelled as a yes/no problem in which *yes* means that the coin is definitely in a certain set, and *no* means that it is definitely not in a certain set. It’s a completely different kind of information, and I really don’t think that there’s any straightforward direct comparison.